# React-Admin Simple Refresh JWT Token

Tags: reactjs, jwt, react-admin

I have an react-admin with an auth provider like the below.
I want to refresh my token, but I don't know how to do it.
I tried to follow this [blog post](https://marmelab.com/blog/2020/07/02/manage-your-jwt-react-admin-authentication-in-memory.html), but my auth is a little different and I can't make it work (the error  "httpClient(...).then" is not a function and others make me leave it).

I can make it with a more simple solution, does not need to be in memory. I tried to call my refresh endpoint to get my refresh token, but my call go without the current token.

My endpoint to refresh the token is:
/auth/jwt/refresh

I need to call it like this:

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://localhost:8000/auth/jwt/refresh' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

And My response body would be: (and I need to save it to my localstorage or the in memory way)

```
{
  "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiZTUwZDdhZDctOWE5Ni00NzQyLTgxNWEtZTNmZmJmNGRiMTVjIiwiYXVkIjpbImZhc3RhcGktdXNlcnM6YXV0aCJdLCJleHAiOjE2Mzk4NDE1MDF9.-o2yk56sCj_MZx_VA6PxH7gZ-KKSMmopbDNDiapHmn0",
  "token_type": "bearer"
}
```

My inMemoryJWTManager file:

```
const inMemoryJWTManager = () => {
    let inMemoryJWT = null;
    let isRefreshing = null;
    let logoutEventName = 'ra-logout';
    let refreshEndpoint = '/auth/jwt/refresh';
    let refreshTimeOutId;

    const setLogoutEventName = name => logoutEventName = name;
    const setRefreshTokenEndpoint = endpoint => refreshEndpoint = endpoint;

    // This countdown feature is used to renew the JWT before it's no longer valid
    // in a way that is transparent to the user.
    const refreshToken = (delay) => {
        refreshTimeOutId = window.setTimeout(
            getRefreshedToken,
            delay * 1000 - 5000
        ); // Validity period of the token in seconds, minus 5 seconds
    };

    const abordRefreshToken = () => {
        if (refreshTimeOutId) {
            window.clearTimeout(refreshTimeOutId);
        }
    };

    const waitForTokenRefresh = () => {
        if (!isRefreshing) {
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
        return isRefreshing.then(() => {
            isRefreshing = null;
            return true;
        });
    }

    // The method make a call to the refresh-token endpoint
    // If there is a valid cookie, the endpoint will set a fresh jwt in memory.
    const getRefreshedToken = () => {
        const request = new Request(refreshEndpoint, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
            credentials: 'include',
        });

        isRefreshing = fetch(request)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.status !== 200) {
                    ereaseToken();
                    global.console.log(
                        'Token renewal failure'
                    );
                    return { token: null };
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(({ token, tokenExpiry }) => {
                if (token) {
                    setToken(token, tokenExpiry);
                    return true;
                }
                ereaseToken();
                return false;
            });

        return isRefreshing;
    };


    const getToken = () => inMemoryJWT;

    const setToken = (token, delay) => {
        inMemoryJWT = token;
        refreshToken(delay);
        return true;
    };

    const ereaseToken = () => {
        inMemoryJWT = null;
        abordRefreshToken();
        window.localStorage.setItem(logoutEventName, Date.now());
        return true;
    }

    // This listener will allow to disconnect a session of ra started in another tab
    window.addEventListener('storage', (event) => {
        if (event.key === logoutEventName) {
            inMemoryJWT = null;
        }
    });

    return {
        ereaseToken,
        getRefreshedToken,
        getToken,
        setLogoutEventName,
        setRefreshTokenEndpoint,
        setToken,
        waitForTokenRefresh,
    }
};

export default inMemoryJWTManager();
```

This is my auth provider: (updated, using inMemoryJWTManager)

```
import inMemoryJWTManager from './inMemoryJWT'
const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8000'

const authProvider = {
    login: ({username, password}) => {

        const oAuthParams = {
            username,
            password
        }
        const body = Object.keys(oAuthParams).map((key) => {
            return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(oAuthParams[key]);
          }).join('&');

        const request = new Request(`${apiUrl}/auth/jwt/login`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: body,
            headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}),
        }); 
        return fetch(request)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
                    throw new Error(response.statusText);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(( {access_token} ) => {
                inMemoryJWTManager.setToken(access_token);
            }); 
    },
    checkError: (error) => {
        const status = error.status;
        if (status === 401 || status === 403) {
            inMemoryJWTManager.ereaseToken();
            return Promise.reject({redirectTo: '/login'});
        }
        // other error code (404, 500, etc): no need to log out
        return Promise.resolve();
    },
    checkAuth: () => inMemoryJWTManager.getToken()
    ? Promise.resolve()
    : Promise.reject({ message: 'Login necessário', redirectTo: 'login' }),

    logout: () => {
        inMemoryJWTManager.ereaseToken();
        return Promise.resolve();
    },

    getPermissions: () => {
        return inMemoryJWTManager.getToken() ? Promise.resolve() : Promise.reject();
    },
};

export default authProvider;
```

My updated httpClient code using inMemoryJWTManager: (and I'm using: `const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider(apiUrl, httpClient);` with modifications to it, but I think it is irrelevant)

```
const httpClient = (url) => {
    const options = {
        headers: new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' }),
    };
    const token = inMemoryJWTManager.getToken();
    console.log(token)

    if (token) {
        options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
        return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
    } else {
        inMemoryJWTManager.setRefreshTokenEndpoint(`${apiUrl}/auth/jwt/refresh`);
        return inMemoryJWTManager.getRefreshedToken().then((gotFreshToken) => {
            if (gotFreshToken) {
                options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${inMemoryJWTManager.getToken()}`);
            };
            return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
        });
    }
};
```

My problem is that, when I call my refresh token endpoint, my request go without the `{'Authorization': Bearer...` and it is not renewed and I got logged out. The other endpoints are fine, they go with the token.

Comment: Is this a spa? what flow are you using?

Comment: "What I simple want to do is get and update my token in every call to my api." That's not how things work. The access token is a JWT (JSON Web token) and has a certain lifetime. You can view your access token at https://jwt.io/.  For renewing your access tokens you have a couple of options: https://auth0.com/docs/login/configure-silent-authentication for spas and then https://auth0.com/docs/security/tokens/refresh-tokens is for say hybrid flow.

Comment: ah never mind, seems you are using the hybrid flow with refresh tokens...

Comment: Yeah, it is a single SPA (with React-Admin). I'm not using an auth provider like auth0

Comment: what are you using as your auth provider? And, for SPAs you should either be using implict or auth code w/pkse protection flows. And, for that you'll want to do a silent renew.

Comment: what you are asking for is probably not implementable... here's why, say your token has expired then the API call will fail. And, you don't want to rely on your API calls to 'update' your token.

Comment: @SangeetAgarwal, thanks for your thoughts. My auth provider is in my question above. A link for an article of an example of what I want is in the question too, but it didn't work for me. If my call fails, the next good call would renew it. I think you need to know React-Admin to better understanding. Here they talk about the auth providers: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authentication.html . If you have some link about the type of implementation you think is good to my case, please share it.

Comment: All what you want just described in article with examples https://marmelab.com/blog/2020/07/02/manage-your-jwt-react-admin-authentication-in-memory.html#solving-optimistic-rendering-problems  . See about  `httpClient` ,  `inMemoryJWTManager.getRefreshedToken `  and you find your answer.

Comment: @VitaliyRayets it didn't work, after many tries (I have to change it, because my authentication in the backend is different), even when I thought it was right, I get: `"httpClient(...).then" is not a function`.

Comment: Share your `httpClient` code

Comment: @VitaliyRayets I edited my question an put the code near the end

Answer (score 1):

You must check token expire before each requests, if token expired you must get new from `/auth/jwt/refresh`, then you can send current request. All this information is in the article [post](https://marmelab.com/blog/2020/07/02/manage-your-jwt-react-admin-authentication-in-memory.html). Example:

```
const httpClient = (url) => {
    const options = {
        headers: new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' }),
    };
    const token = inMemoryJWT.getToken();

    if (token) {
        options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
        return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
    } else {
        inMemoryJWT.setRefreshTokenEndpoint('http://localhost:8001/refresh-token');
        return inMemoryJWT.getRefreshedToken().then((gotFreshToken) => {
            if (gotFreshToken) {
                options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${inMemoryJWT.getToken()}`);
            };
            return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried, but I receive a "Token renewal failure" because my current token is not going with my header request... How can I send it?

Comment: `Token renewal failure` because you miss `Authorization` headers, just set correct headers to you refresh token request `{'Authorization': Bearer ${inMemoryJWT.getToken()})}`

Comment: I don't know how to do that. To other endpoints, my headers are correct, but to the refresh endpoint, it go without the `{'Authorization': Bearer...`
I updated my code above, including my `inMemoryJWTManager` and `authProvider` and `httpClient` updated

Comment: I changed it, and I now send the bearer to the refresh endpoint (changing the `getRefreshedToken` from `inMemoryJW`. But I receive `Status: 304
Not Modified`.  And the Cache from the response is: `Expires: 2/7/2106 3:28:15 AM`. I don't understand this cache, my token lasts 24 hours.

Comment: Forget it, anyway, if I hit F5, it does not send the Bearer, and if I navigate to other resource, it does not send too.

Comment: thanks. I give you the bounty. Your answer help me to see some errors in my code, but unfortunately I couldn't make it work because of the explained above... I don't know how to always (I thought my current code would do it) send the Bearer in the calls to refresh point. I tried, but I don't have an advanced knowledge of react or react-admin.